# Problema con el StartDate en periodo de fechas PHP (DatePeriod)

Tags: php, date, datetime

estoy intentando realizar una función que me seleccione unicamente los días de un rango determinado de fechas que coincidan con la condición de un periodo de tiempo (por ejemplo: los primeros viernes de cada mes, los último viernes de cada mes, todos los viernes, etc...), he estado buscando como poder hacerlo y parece que la clase DatePeriod de php es una buena opción.

Uno de los problemas que me he encontrado ha sido que en este rango de fechas no se estaba incluyendo el  `$endDay` pero aumentándole un segundo al tiempo   `$end->setTime(0,0,1);` he solucionado esto.

Ahora bien, no ocurre lo mismo con el  `$startDay`, en este caso cuando genero un periodo parece estar ignorando que la fecha de inicio cumpla con la condición del periodo.

Este es mi código:

**PHP**

```
/* http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.relative.php */
function daysByPeriod($startDay,$endDay,$inter){
    $start    = new DateTime($startDay);
    $end      = new DateTime($endDay);

    // Arreglo para incluir la fecha fin al periodo
    $end->setTime(0,0,1);

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($inter);
    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    foreach ($period as $dt) {
      echo $dt->format("l Y-m-d") . "<br>";
    }
  }

$dateStart1='20170706';
$dateEnd1='20180105';
echo "<strong>Primer viernes</strong> del mes del $dateStart1 al $dateEnd1<br>";
// Está incluyendo el día 2017-07-06 que no es viernes
// No está pintando el día 2017-07-07 que es viernes
daysByPeriod($dateStart1,$dateEnd1,'first friday of next month');

$dateStart2='20170525';
$dateEnd2='20180105';
echo "<strong>Último viernes</strong> del mes del $dateStart2 al $dateEnd2<br>";
// Está incluyendo el día 2017-05-25 que no es viernes
// No está pintando el día 2017-05-26 que es viernes
daysByPeriod($dateStart2,$dateEnd2,'last friday of next month');

$dateStart3='20170805';
$dateEnd3='20180105';
echo "Cada <strong>mes</strong> del $dateStart3 al $dateEnd3<br>";
// Aquí incluye la fecha inicio sin problema dentro el rango
daysByPeriod($dateStart3,$dateEnd3,'1 month'); 

$dateStart4='20170622';
$dateEnd4='20180105';
echo "Los <strong>viernes</strong> del $dateStart4 al $dateEnd4<br>";
// Está incluyendo el día 2017-06-22 que no es viernes
// Aquí incluye la fecha inicio sin problema dentro el rango
daysByPeriod($dateStart4,$dateEnd4,'next friday');
```

¿Alguien podría echarme una mano con esto? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un intervalo salta desde la fecha indicada hasta la siguiente fecha según la condición. En el primer caso parte de la fecha 2017/07/06

> 2017/07/06 -> salta un mes hasta el primer viernes ->
>   2017/08/04

Aquí ya has perdido el viernes del mes 07 (por eso no te aparece) y te aparece el día 06 del mes 07 porque es tu inicio del intervalo.

El mismo problema ocurre con el siguiente ejemplo. Deberías empezar el intervalo en el día que necesitas, ya sea colocandolo a mano, o calculándolo previamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta, pensaba que la propia clase revisaba día por día del rango por eso en los ejemplos estaba poniendo unos días antes y no el día exacto para la fecha inicio que coincidía con la condición. Aún así sigo sin entender muy bien por que no está sacando los días d inicio hice una prueba con $dateStart1='20170707'; que es el día exacto que quiero empezar el intervalo que es viernes y quiero que me lo pinte  y aún así no lo incluye en el rango ¿que estoy haciendo mal esta vez?

Comment: Me resulta extraño, lo he ejecutado en consola y me obtiene bien esa fecha: Friday 2017-07-07
<br/>Friday 2017-08-04
<br/>Friday 2017-09-01
<br/>Friday 2017-10-06
<br/>Friday 2017-11-03
<br/>Friday 2017-12-01
<br/>Friday 2018-01-05
<br/>

Comment: Cierto, ha sido fallo mío me faltó comentar una línea, ahora si me está devolviendo esa fecha gracias de nuevo :)